# How to do filtering for multiple conditions with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, filter

In the following example code, how can I filter out only those rows of "Sell" in the "Status" element and more than 30% in the "Profit" element from the "data" variable, using the "criteria" variable?  Can anyone help me out finish the code?   I used to use Google Sheets filter functions, SpreadsheetApp.new filter criteria().whenNumber..., but it took so long (5 minutes) to refresh my Google Sheets, as my actual application has 3000 rows and 140 columns to filter and required so many calls.  Rather I learn how to do filtering operations within the JavaScript level, expecting that it would be much faster.  Then I can send the filtered data back to Google Sheets.  Thank you for any help!

```
function test() {

  var data = [['Product', 'Status', 'Price', 'Profit'],
  ['Apple', 'Hold', 10, '10%'],
  ['Mango', 'Sell', 20, '20%'],
  ['Orange', 'Buy', 30, '30%'],
  ['Juice', 'Sell', 40, '40%'],
  ['Coffee', 'Sell', 50, '50%']];
  data.splice(0, 1);  // Remove header

  var criteria = ['', 'Sell', '', '>30%'];
  var filteredData = data;

  for (var i = 0; i < criteria.length; ++i) {
    if (criteria[i]) {
      filteredData = filteredData.filter(???);
      console.log(filteredData);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: convert your array to object array first, then you may try this ```const myArrayFiltered = filteredData.filter( el => {
  return criteria.some( f => {
    return f.Status === el.Status && f.Profit === el.Profit;
  });
});```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  If my application deals with just a few column data, your suggestion makes perfect sense.  However, my application deals with 140 columns, so it's quite challenging to write the code in your suggestion.  Rather I need to figure it out a method to loop by column index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate all criteria along with their column values and check the value or calculate the percent value.

```js
const
    criteria = ['', 'Sell', '', '>30%'],
    data = [['Product', 'Status', 'Price', 'Profit'], ['Apple', 'Hold', 10, '10%'], ['Mango', 'Sell', 20, '20%'], ['Orange', 'Buy', 30, '30%'], ['Juice', 'Sell', 40, '40%'], ['Coffee', 'Sell', 50, '50%']],
    result = data
        .slice(1)
        .filter(a => criteria.every((c, i) => {
            if (!c || c === a[i]) return true;
            if (c.slice(-1) === '%') return eval(a[i].slice(0, -1) + c.slice(0, -1));
        }));
        
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The best solution I like most!  It works!  Thank you!  Could you explain how eval(a[i].slice(0, -1) + c.slice(0, -1)) does work?  For instance, what if I want >=30%, but <45%?  Thanks again!

Comment: [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) takes a string as code and evaluates it. [`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) takes a substring. if you like to use twi conditions, you  need a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

`.filter`, `.map`, `.reduce`, `.forEach` and other similar functions,
have some options regarding the parameters you can pass, you can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

For this use-case, you actually don't need `criteria` at all,
you can simply do:

```js
function test() {

  var data = [['Product', 'Status', 'Price', 'Profit'],
  ['Apple', 'Hold', 10, '10%'],
  ['Mango', 'Sell', 20, '20%'],
  ['Orange', 'Buy', 30, '30%'],
  ['Juice', 'Sell', 40, '40%'],
  ['Coffee', 'Sell', 50, '50%']];
  data.splice(0, 1);  // Remove header

  var filteredData = data;
  filteredData = filteredData.filter(currentData => {
      if (currentData[1] === 'Sell' && parseInt(currentData[3]) > 30) {
         return currentData;
      }
     });
  }
```

After this is done, `filteredData` gets filled with 'Juice' and 'Coffee' arrays in this case, and then you can do whatever you need with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
function test() {
  var data = [['Product', 'Status', 'Price', 'Profit'],
  ['Apple', 'Hold', 10, '10%'],
  ['Mango', 'Sell', 20, '20%'],
  ['Orange', 'Buy', 30, '30%'],
  ['Juice', 'Sell', 40, '40%'],
  ['Coffee', 'Sell', 50, '50%']];
  data.shift();
  let fdata = data.filter(r => r[1] == 'Sell' && parseInt(r[3]) > 30);
  Logger.log(fdata.join('\n'));
}

1:45:07 PM  Notice  Execution started
1:45:08 PM  Info    Juice,Sell,40,40%
Coffee,Sell,50,50%
1:45:08 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```